# Update z-index of new graphic layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am creating/drawing a new polyline successfully; the only problem is it's going under my other graphic layers. Is there any ability to set the z-index of this to bring it above the over layers? I read in 4.x there is this ability with 'collections' but I find the documentation very vague.

```
  var graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
  map.add(graphicsLayer);

  var simpleLineSymbol = {
      type: "simple-line",
      color: [13, 121, 190, 1],
      style: "short-dash",
      width: 5
  };
 ..............


    var polyline = {
        type: "polyline",
        paths: [
            [lineY, lineX],
            [coordinatesBx, coordinatesBy]
        ]
    };
    var polylineGraphic = new Graphic({
        geometry: polyline,
        symbol: simpleLineSymbol
    })
```

Comment: Did you try specifying an index when calling the [add](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-core-Collection.html#add) method?

Comment: This is how I am adding it;                 graphicsLayer.add(polylineGraphic)

Comment: Yeah I dont really understand the example in that documentation, I find their documentation not very explicit

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the graphics in the same layer, then you can play with the order of the graphics (check @Kirk Kyukendall comment). By default, the graphics are added to the end of the list so it is render on top of the other graphics of the layer. You can think the index of the graphics in the list as their z.

If the problem are other graphics from another layer, then you can play with the order of the layers in the map. The layers are render in the order of the list. The usual order is polygons, then lines, then points.

Comment: That is problem the points are overlapping my new PolyLine so you can barely see the lines

Comment: I know what you mean, making a map is an art. I suggest you that instead of trying to resolve it by "code", your work on the style of the layers, try different size, colors, markers, etc.